# Access to a variable in a dynamic form

Tags: php

I've written a dynamic form that will ask for hours and mins (still don't have the proper restrictions set up). My problem with this form is, how do I access the variables values?

The user is asked to type a number and then the program displays `n` forms so the user can type some times of the day.

My code is as follows:

```
echo "How many times?<br>";
    ?>
        <form action="complex_tar2.php" method="POST">
            <input type="number" name="periodos" step="1" min="1" max="100">
            <input type="submit" value="avancar">
        </form>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['periodos']))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['periodos']))
        {
            $max = $_POST['periodos'];
            ?>
                <form action="complex_tar2.php" method="POST">
                    <?php 
/*****************************************************************************/
                        for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++)
                        {
                            ?>
                                Hours ---------------------------- Minutes<br>
                                <input type="number" name="h" step="1" min="0" max="23">: 
                                <input type="number" name="m" step="1" min="0" max="59"><br>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Registar">
                </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['h']) && isset($_POST['m']))
            {
                echo $_POST['h']." ".$_POST['m'].'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
```

The division is set so its easier to see the part that I have a doubt. I know that `h` and `m` are not set properly, thats the part I have a doubt. And I've also tried setting them as `"h".($i+1)` and `"m".($i+1)` , however it gave the same result.

Comment: WHICH  dynamic var. u want to access? Not clear yet.

Comment: `name="h[<?php echo $i;?>]"` to retreive posted values `var_dump($_POST['h']);//outputs array`

Comment: you can set `name="h[<?php echo $i ?>]"` then at the start of `complex_tar2.php` try out `<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die();?>`

Comment: Cheers for the answers guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 <input type="number" name="m[]" step="1" min="0" max="59"><br>
 <input type="number" name="h[]" step="1" min="0" max="59"><br>
```

And to manipulate

For m & h

```
foreach ($_POST["m"] as $singleM) {
}

foreach ($_POST["h"] as $singleH) {
}
```

As `m` and `h` are arrays

Answer (score 2):

U can use:

`<input type="number" name="h_<? echo $i; ?>" step="1" min="0" max="23">
<input type="number" name="m_<? echo $i; ?>" step="1" min="0" max="59">`

and do the loop :

```
     for($i = 0 ; $i < $max ; $i++)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['h_'.$i]) && isset($_POST['m_'.$i]))
            {
                echo $_POST['h_'.$i]." ".$_POST['m_'.$i].'<br>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cheers, I've check yours and the above answers and both work like I wanted to.